# 2 web servers' application accessing the same data

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, iis-7.5, iscsi

I've been tasked to find for a solution that will allow me to use 1 storage location for 2 different web servers' applicaiton data.  My problem is that these 2 web servers will both be accessing the same files.  I need a way to lock the file if 1 server is using the file so it can't be accessed by the other server until the server is done accessing the file.
I'm using licensed VMware ESXi 4.1 for my hosts, Windows 2008 r2 web edition with IIS.  I have both of these servers hooked into redundant switches going to an iSCSI San.
I'm told that I need a 3rd party software that will allow me to do this, because I'll be using ntfs for my SAN Volume that will store the data.
This is an active/active configuration.

Does anyone have any idea how I can make this work or what other software I might need to control the file accesss.  I'm told that this ability is not suppported natively in Windows 2008 web or IIS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use Active/Active is the simplest no-additional-software solution.
- NLB in failover mode (rather than balancing mode) might work too.
- Using an external load balancer that directs traffic only to one node at a time is the other (if you need lots of applications on the servers, and this is just one, this might be the way to go).
- Implementing MSCS clustering might work, but IIS doesn't natively support it, so you'll need to implement your own scripts.
- If you know the developer of the application, ask them whether/how they support multi-instancing, and whether they can rewrite/support/recommend anything.

Comment: TristanK,  I know the developer and it does not support multi-instancing.

Comment: do you know what the best external load balancer is?

Comment: Not with any authority. An F5 at the high end; Application Request Routing at the low end.